# How to query for users where one set is deeper in the tree than the other

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Let's say you have two sets of users:

`OU=IT Dept,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com`

`OU=XYZ Corp,OU=Temp Accounts,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com`

How would you express the query for that? I tried a search base of `OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com` and a filter of `(|(OU=IT Dept)(OU=XYZ Corp,OU=Temp Accounts))` and that didn't work.

Never had to do much with LDAP, so please excuse the somewhat open-ended question.

Comment: You can choose one of 2 option here: make 2 ldap queries for each path or make one query for the common path and filter users from other ou's on the client side. The first option is more preferable from the performance point of view

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. Thanks for confirming what I suspected. The app I'm tweaking doesn't have the flexibility to do either that filtering or the multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say you have two sets of users:
>
> OU=IT Dept,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com
>
> OU=XYZ Corp,OU=Temp Accounts,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com

These are not the valid distinguishedName for user objects.

User objects are stored in some parent container (like OUs), and their distinguishedName starts with CN. OUs are top level containers which contain child objects like users, computers, child OUs, etc.

> I tried a search base of OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com and a filter of
>   (|(OU=IT Dept)(OU=XYZ Corp,OU=Temp Accounts)) and that didn't work.

Your filter didn't work because you didn't select the appropriate filtering conditions. You need to apply the filter for `(objectCategory=person)` or `(objectCategory=user)`.  You can also use `objectClass` as the filtering parameter instead of objectCategory. Check the link [`Filter on objectCategory and objectClass`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) to know in detail.

> How would you express the query for that?

Assuming your users are as below:

CN=Firstname lastname,OU=IT Dept,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com
CN=Firstname lastname,OU=XYZ Corp,OU=Temp Accounts,OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com

Then your LDAP query should have `SearchBase` set to what you currently have (`OU=Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com`), and filter on `(|(objectCategory=person)(objectCategory=user))` and any additional filter if you'd like, e.g., you may want to search by sAMAccountName, name, etc.

As highlighted in the second para, you can also use `objectClass` as the filter type to get the desired result.